# IE not loading ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a script the loads data via ajax, splits it, reverses it and displays it on the page. As usual all it's working great on all browsers except the dreaded IE. It throws up no errors in IE, just does not load. I am using Twitter Bootstrap, jQuery v1.7.1. Please help if you can. Cheers

```
$.ajax({
      url: "insert_URL_here",
      success: function(data){

        var number_box = $('.number_box');
        var number_list = data.split("");

        number_list.reverse();

        for(var i=0; i < number_box.length; i++)
        {

          if(number_list.length > i)
          {
              $(".unit_"+i).html(number_list[i]);
          }
          else
          {
              $(".unit_"+i).html("0");
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: how are you calling `$.ajax`? What code you have around it?

Comment: Just a $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: Have you checked network tab (if ie9+) ? Or if ie7-8 - fiddler?

Comment: Also - did you tried to debug step-by-step to see what is going on there?

Comment: Yes, I don't see anything from the load in Network

Comment: strange. Such code should work. "insert_URL_here" - is it some variable or just a string?

Comment: That's just something I put instead of the real url. It works great in FF, Chrome, just not IE.

Comment: May be you could try printing out the data under success, by console.log(data) and tell us what you see on the console?

Comment: Hi, I tried that, it prints it in Chrome and FF but not it IE. It's like IE is totally ignoring the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the dataType property to json ..

If you are expecting your request data to be in json format..

```
dataType : 'json'  and also the data 

$.ajax({
      url: 'insert_URL_here',
      data : '{}',
      dataType : 'text',  // OR  dataType : 'html',
      success :
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it stops the data loading on all browsers.

Comment: Hm. data.split("") is used which means that string is expected, not JS object

Comment: @ClintonGreen .. Try dataType: 'text' instead.. And also check if you see any errors in the console section page